# Mongoose update array element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have fallowing schema:

```
var CountrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    relations : { type: Number, default: 0, min : 0, max : 1},    
});

var DiplomacySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    year: { type: Number, default: 1900, min : 1900, max: 2020 },
    countries: [CountrySchema]
});
```

with the corresponding document in the database

```
{
   year: 1950,
   countries: [
      {
         name: "UK",
         relations: 0.5    
      },
      {
         name: "Germany",
         relations: 0.25    
      } 
   ]
}
```

I need to update UK current relations by some number, under constraint that updated value stays in the range boundaries. For example considering current UK relations is 0.5, update of +0.25 should lead to 0.75, update of -0.3 should result in 0.2, but update of +0.75  should be 1.

Comment: Youre post doesn't really ask a clear question.  Are you having trouble with updating the number in the database, accessing yourJSONobject.countries[0].relations within that JSON object, or with the math(hopefully sarcasm)?

Comment: I'm having a problem with updating the number, since I need to calculate updated value using the old value as an input. It would be easy to use set or increment, but I must to keep the updated value within the boundaries [0,1].

Comment: Why this is so special then? you just need to calculate the value first and then use `$set` to update.

Comment: You mean to use findOne, calculate the value, then call $set. If I want to update the Germany too with different value, should I call $set twice or use save  ?